# Cannot change Grub anymore

Tags: boot, grub2

After installing Ubuntu 20.04, I wanted to adjust my grub because I wanted to get rid of the 10s waiting time (I used "sudo gedit /etc/default/grub"). And for some reason, it also goed to GRUB-default position 5.

It now looks like this:

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full **documentation** of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'
GRUB_DEFAULT="Ubuntu"
#GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE="hidden"
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT="0"
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET="true"
GRUB_TIMEOUT="1"
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"
# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL="console"
# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE="640x480"
# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID="true"
# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"
# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT="false"
GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER="true"
```

After that I used "sudo update-grub" to update the grub.

However, the startup did not change.

I also used the Grub customizer, but waiting time is still 10 sec and it is going to the 5th item in the list

Anybody any idea?

Regards, Mark

Answer (score 0):

Don't know for sure, but I use grub-customizer all the time. It's a lifesaver!

I ran it and under the General Settings tab, my boot entry is "(first entry)", not "Ubuntu". It's the first choice in the drop-down menu.

That screen also has a field for setting the menu timeout interval. If it says 10 seconds there, you can adjust it down. If it already says 1 second, then something's wrong. In that case, you might want to post a question on the grub-customizer page on [launchpad](https://launchpad.net/grub-customizer). I haven't posted there in quite some time, but when I did, Daniel Richter was very helpful.